# Core Data Save Return False, But Error is nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, save

I recently added a new 'optional one to many relationship' into my core data model and now I am getting 'NO' from [managedObjectContext save:&error].
But error returned is nil.

Any Clue?

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] == YES)
    {
        BOOL isSaved = [managedObjectContext save:&error];

        if (isSaved == YES && error == nil)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Context Saving Error = %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            return error;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Context Has No Changes To Save

        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even I also added 'accessory(new model)' into newly added optional relationship.

Answer (score 0):

One of my ValidateAttribute validator was mistakenly returning false.